# Display random item from an array as soon the script is loaded and save the occurence in another array

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I need to show some random animal name in different colors that both change when pressing some keyboard key and then save in what order they where displayed. My problem is that the first random animal name in random color is displayed only after I press either the "r" or "t" keyboard key, instead of appearing as soon as the script start. I've tried adding them outside the event listener function, but then I'm not able to save they occurence in the saveData array and I'd like to avoid having to add code just to save the first occurence if not necessary. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="animals" id="animals"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

show like this:

```
const showAnimal = () => {
    const animals = {"dog": "yellow", "cat":"black", "fish":"blue","mouse":"gray"};
    const colors = Object.keys(animals);
    const name = Object.values(animals);

    const numOfAnimals = 15; 
    let num = 0;    
    var saveData = []

    const selectRandomFeature = (name, colors) => {
        const randomTextIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);   
        const randomColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); 

        var randomText = name[randomTextIndex];  
        const randomColor = colors[randomColorIndex];

        return [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex, randomColorIndex];
    }

    const displayAnimals = (randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex) => {
        if (num < numOfAnimals - 1) {        
            document.getElementById("animals").innerText  = `${randomColor}`;   
            document.getElementById("animals").style.color = randomText;

            console.log(randomColor);
            console.log(randomText);
        } else {
            console.log(saveData)
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        const [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex] = selectRandomFeature(name, colors);

        if (event.key === 'r') {            
            if (randomTextIndex == randomColorIndex) {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"left"})
            } else {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"left"})
            }          
            displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex);  
            num++;   
        } else if (event.key === 't') { 

            if (randomTextIndex == randomColorIndex) {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"righ"})
            } else {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"right"})
            }   
            displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex);         
            num++;                        
        }        
    });
}  
showAnimal()
```

How can I show a random name in random color as soon as my script start and be sure is saved in the saveData array alongside the following one that appear when clicking the keyboard key?

Answer (score 1):

Hi ✋ i maybe found a solution you could try

1. First i put all yours code out of showAnimals function
2. Then i splited code in different function to be more readable
3. Remove some duplicate code with same logic
4. Finally i created a function that implement your logic in eventListener and call it when page it's loaded `addAnimal(direction)`

```js
//Puts everything out of showAnimal()
const animals = { dog: "yellow", cat: "black", fish: "blue", mouse: "gray" };
const colors = Object.keys(animals);
const name = Object.values(animals);

const numOfAnimals = 15;
let num = 0;

//As a global variable, it's accessible everywhere in the scope
var saveData = [];

const displayAnimals = (
  randomText,
  randomColor
  //Remove two unnecassary parameters (randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex)
) => {
  if (num < numOfAnimals - 1) {
    document.getElementById("animals").innerText = `${randomColor}`;
    document.getElementById("animals").style.color = randomText;

    console.log(randomColor);
    console.log(randomText);
  } else {
    console.log(saveData);
  }
};

const selectRandomFeature = (name, colors) => {
  const randomTextIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
  const randomColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

  var randomText = name[randomTextIndex];
  const randomColor = colors[randomColorIndex];

  return [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex, randomColorIndex];
};

//Direction can be 'left' or 'right'
const addAnimal = (direction) => {
  const [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex, randomColorIndex] =
    selectRandomFeature(name, colors);

  saveData.push({
    text: randomText,
    color: randomColor,
    direction: direction,
  });

  displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex, randomColorIndex);

  num++;
};

/*
    In your event listener you have some duplication code
    If condition (randomTextIndex == randomColorIndex) is true or not your doing the same logic
    Also you execute displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex`; and num++; even if your keydown it's 'r' or 't'
*/
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "r" || event.key == "t") {
    //Ternary operator condition if value else otherValue
    const direction = event.key == "r" ? "left" : "right"; 
    addAnimal(direction);
  }
});

//Call for the first time
addAnimal("right");
```

Hope this solution will help you ‍♂️.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me, my only problem is that I'm missing the first user's direction input since is always "right" due `addAnimal("right");`. is there a way to catch that also?

Comment: I've just realized that all the saved directoin are wrong and refer to the previous saved name and colors displayed. This is pretty much the same problem I had before

Answer (score 1):

It did not load when the page loaded because the function is only called on the eventListener. You can call the function before the eventListener and save the values in the array. Also on line 49 of your code you are missing a "t" at direction:right. Here is the code I changed. Please let me know what you think of it.

```
 const displayAnimals = (randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex) => {
        if (num < numOfAnimals - 1) {        
            document.getElementById("animals").innerText  = `${randomColor}`;   
            document.getElementById("animals").style.color = randomText;

            console.log(randomColor);
            console.log(randomText);
        } else {
            console.log(saveData)
        }
    }

    const [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex] = selectRandomFeature(name, colors);

    saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction": randomColorIndex})
    // call function here so it shows when script loads
    displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex, randomColorIndex);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        const [randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex] = selectRandomFeature(name, colors);

        if (event.key === 'r') {            
            if (randomTextIndex == randomColorIndex) {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"left"})
            } else {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"left"})
            }          
            displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex);  
            num++;   
        } else if (event.key === 't') { 

            if (randomTextIndex == randomColorIndex) {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"right"})
            } else {
                saveData.push({"text": randomText, "color": randomColor, "direction":"right"})
            }   
            displayAnimals(randomText, randomColor, randomTextIndex , randomColorIndex);         
            num++;                        
        }        
    });
}  
showAnimal()
```